# using progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I was trying to use a progress bar in my application - on a click of a button, a new layout with a progress bar widget on it should be displayed -  i tried following code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){

                 case R.id.Button:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, progbar.class);         
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }


public class progbar extends Activity{

    private ProgressBar prgbar;
    private int prgStatus = 0;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.lProgbar);

        prgbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ReceiveUAI_prg);

     // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (prgStatus < 100) {
                    prgStatus += 2;

                    // Update the progress bar
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            prgbar.setProgress(prgStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

but my application gets terminated on clicking the button.

Comment: What are the details in stack trace?

Comment: does stack trace means logcat or the console?

Comment: Yeah, logcat. It shows the details of exception.

Comment: 03-29 15:34:25.206: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(291): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 15:34:25.206: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(291): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sigpro.CTransfer/sigpro.CTransfer.prodbar}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout

Comment: Check out, this line is working properly `prgbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ReceiveUAI_prg);`.

Comment: yes! there is no problem in that line...

Comment: Then check the next lines. You are casting incompatible objects somewhere.

Comment: is there any other way i can use progressbar??

Comment: I've used the `ProgressDialog`. I used two differenct threads, one for the operation and other to update the progress. I used them along with the `Handler`. You can also try this approach.

Comment: would you please give me an example of how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

put a progressbar in R.layout.lProgbar at design time. when you are done with it call progressbar.GONE, which will remove the progressbar.

Comment: i have already added it in design time... and as the progress bar does not appear only(my application get crashed) no meaning in getting it closed!!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the thread , Also you are not giving a delay in updating your progress bar status..so it ends up quickly..try this

```
 while (prgStatus < 100) {
                prgStatus += 2;

                // Update the progress bar
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        prgbar.setProgress(prgStatus);
                    }
                },200);
```